# Active Collab. Can't get time-records via REST API

Tags: api, activecollab

I'm trying to get task info via Active Collab REST API and have a problem.
I got token by login and password and successfully made a request on next URL's:

`GET on https://app.activecollab.com/ACCOUNT_ID/api/v1/projects`
`GET on https://app.activecollab.com/ACCOUNT_ID/api/v1/projects/1`

But I receive 404 on:

`GET on https://app.activecollab.com/ACCOUNT_ID/api/v1/projects/1/time-records`

I found this endpoint in the documentation

https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/elements/time-records/time-records.html

Could you please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time tracking is not enabled by default per project. You can make sure that you enable it when you create a project (or update project's settings), or check whether it is enabled in your code.

To check if it is enabled, you can probe for 404 on `/projects/:project_id/time-records` API end point, or you can check for `is_tracking_enabled` property in response that you get from `/projects/:project_id` API response.